# Form that generates an ID for the customer

Tags: plugins, forms, id

I wonder if this is possible on wordpress. In my application I will have a contact form, in this contact form, when filling in the fields, there must be a field that will generate an ID. This ID the customer will be able to write down and save. I will also receive this ID along with the details this person has filled in.
It is possible? Or is there already a plugin for this type of situation?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't provide contact forms by default. So either you'll have to use a form plugin or you'll need custom CODE anyway.

Since you didn't provide any CODE or reference to any plugin you're going to use, I cannot provide a sample CODE that'll work for you. In principle, plugins do provide custom [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/) that can be used to create the unique ID field for your user. However, make sure you keep that form field disabled and save the value while creating the unique ID (instead of saving after user's form submission), to make sure the ID cannot be altered by the users.

For example, if you use Contact form 7 as your form plugin, then there is a plugin called [UniqueID for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-submission-id/) that provides similar option. You may check that plugin's code and implement your own. Similar implementation is possible for [WP Forms](https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-create-a-unique-id-for-each-form-entry/), and I'm sure other form plugins provide similar options as well.

Answer (score 1):

"Yes, it's possible" you can do this by custom coding. And If you are looking for any plugin you need to first check which contact form you are using.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.